# How to display an icon/image representing the website while we paste URL of site in Facebook post?

Tags: facebook, url, web

when I paste URL of my site on Facebook pages to promote it, it just displays a hyperlink but it doesn't display a favicon, or anyother icon on LHS of the post. For example, if you paste URL of some movie page from imdb.com in your post then it will display some thumbnail sort of thing on LHS which will give good idea about site to the user. How can achieve the similar for my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you paste a url to facebook, it parses the contents of url for specific tags like

```
og:image
og:description
```

to show them in status, which you can make use of.
Find the list here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/open-graph-object/